# Breaking Up a String in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdateformatter, nscharacterset

All,

I have a method that takes a date (YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S) from the database and creates a URL with the year, month and day components from the date string. My solution works but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? How are the cool kids doing it? :-)

Thanks!

```
   -(NSString *) prettyURLFrom:(NSString *)dateString{



    NSString * URLString = @"";
    NSString *URL = @"http://www.theblues.com/featured/article/";

    NSArray *myWords = [dateString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-\" \" :"]
                        ];


    URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@/%@", 
                    URL,
                    [myWords objectAtIndex:1],
                    [myWords objectAtIndex:2],
                    [myWords objectAtIndex:0]];



    return URLString;


   }
```

Comment: Are you retrieving a string or date object from the database?

Comment: Yes. SQLite3. I think I know where you are going - format the string on the database side, right?

Comment: I'm wondering why you weren't passing the date as a NSDate, and returning a string instead of an NSURL.

Comment: Must be my Perl background :-)

Comment: Actually, the URL that ultimately is getting created, is going into a body of text in an email. Not sure if NSURL is needed in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, I find it bizarre you're passing and returning values as strings when they probably should be NSDate and NSURL respectively.

I would probably do something like:

```
-(NSURL*)URLFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    // Assumes user uses a gregorian calendar
    NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

    return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.theblues.com/featured/article/%li/%li/%li"
                                    , [dateComp year]
                                    , [dateComp month]
                                    , [dateComp day]]];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will do something like what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, for anyone working with the examples provided above - The solution that uses NSDateComponents above needs a format specifier %li, not %@ So: http://www.theblues.com/featured/article/%li/%li/%li Thanks to all for the help with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `NSDate` object then you can use

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];
```

NSString to NSDate

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1999-07-02 2:2:4"];
```